# Trouble mapping a simple object to an nnotated index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an index with the following mappings:

```
{
    "term_based_documents": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "catch_all": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "english": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "spanish": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "spanish"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "high_importance_predicates": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "english": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "spanish": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "spanish"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "low_importance_predicates": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "english": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "spanish": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "spanish"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "medium_importance_predicates": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                        "english": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "english"
                        },
                        "raw": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "spanish": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "analyzer": "spanish"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Basically every property is a text field which I want to distinguish from each other.

The object I am feeding the index with looks like this (in Java):

```
public class EntityDocument {
    private String entity;
    public String high_importance_predicates;
    public String medium_importance_predicates;
    public String low_importance_predicates;
    public ArrayList<String> catch_all;

    // ...methods and less interesting stuff
}
```

I am using the (apparently) new ElasticSearch 8.5 Java client, where the request for the inclusion of a new document is the following one:

```
EntityDocument doc = ...;

// Fill the doc

IndexResponse response = client.index(i -> i
                    .index("term_based_documents")
                    .id(doc.entity)
                    .document(doc)
            );

            System.out.println(response);
```

Whenever I add a document, it fails with the following error, without elaborating much on it:

```
failed: [mapper_parsing_exception] failed to parse field [medium_importance_predicates.raw] of type [keyword] in document with id 'http://dbpedia.org/resource/Michael_Schumacher'. Preview of field's value: ' .... '
```

It seems that some parser is failing when adding it, since whenever I simply replace the contents of  `medium_importance_predicates` with something simple as `hello`, it works perfectly. This field contains a lot of untreated `URIs`, non-english characters and some symbols such as `<`, `>`, `[` or `]`, but the other two fields also do contain such characters, although they are smaller.

What could this be?

Comment: Could you provide what is the value of `Preview of field's value: ' ..... '` this part?

Comment: BTW, https://opster.com/es-errors/failed-to-parse-field-of-type-in-document-with-id/ this is really nice article related with this question.